# Crystal Reports - How do you supress sequential data in a column, after the first row, if the data is grouped by that column

Tags: group-by, crystal-reports

Good morning all (10:30am here, AWST),

I have been working on a crystal report and have one final request from the user that I cannot get to the bottom of.

The report is pulling data from SQL and is grouped via Report Grouping by "Description" and "Name" with alphabetical sorting on both groups.

As an example, currently the report output looks something like this:

| Description | Name | Amount | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DESC1 | Sta | $100 | 2022-01-01 |
| DESC1 | Tom | $24 | 2022-01-01 |
| DESC2 | Danny | $50 | 2022-01-24 |
| DESC3 | Elle | $80 | 2022-01-31 |
| DESC3 | Fiona | $75 | 2022-01-31 |
| DESC3 | Fiona | $60 | 2022-01-31 |

To explain the request from the user further, they only want to see the first Description data for each group. For example:

| Description | Name | Amount | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DESC1 | Sta | $100 | 2022-01-01 |
|  | Tom | $24 | 2022-01-01 |
| DESC2 | Danny | $50 | 2022-01-24 |
| DESC3 | Elle | $80 | 2022-01-31 |
|  | Fiona | $75 | 2022-01-28 |
|  | Fiona | $60 | 2022-01-31 |

I am almost certain this request needs to make use of the Section Expert > Suppress area, but after scouring Google and Stack Overflow I'm unable to find a suitable solution so far.

I am using Crystal Reports 2008, Version 12.3.0.601.

Is someone able to please help and point me in the right direction or help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) If you don't use groups (your example looks like that), you can use built-in format option `Suppress if Duplicated` on field "Description".

(2) If you use groups and Description field is placed in group header section, use conditional suppressing of the field (also available in format editor -> formula button next to option `Suppress`). The formula would just be `If InRepeatedGroupHeader`.

(3) If you don't use groups and your version does not provide the function mentioned in (1), you can also use conditional suppressing with a custom formula, then by comparing current to previous record: `If {Description} = Previous({Description}) Then True`

Comment: Apologies for the delay.  It has been a hectic few months. I just wanted to thank you for your response and mark it as the correct answer. I played around with all 3 options, number 2 giving me the best solution. Thanks again and all the best. Cheers.